# EF Core relationships containing external identity

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4

I am trying to improve on a hobby project i got and have been looking at database relationships.
Currently i have 2 solutions:

- GameStoreSolution: registers all of users games, game devices and scores
- IdentityProvider: IdentityServer4 project with AspCoreIdentity, manages identity and authentication

My GameStore contains basic Angular 5 frontend, as well as WebApi Server protected by IdentityProvider server.

What I haven't been able to figure out properly is how do i demonstrate a relationship between authenticated user provided by IdentityProvider and the relevant entities within each individual Store solution?

Currently i have hacked it and duplicated AspCoreIdentity into both solutions and created links via entity objects e.g. below:

```
public class GameDevice {
     public Guid Id {get; set;}
     public ApplicationUser User {get;set;}
}
```

This approach works but is bad if you think about it.

1. It forces IdentityProvider and Web App to share user entity and potentially db
2. Changes in IdentityProvider and cause Web App to throw exceptions if changes are not copyied over
3. Additional Web Apps complicate the relationship model even further causing more headaches
4. Will require to work off same platform/server/db potentially to minimise risks of failure

So my question is, is there a better way to manage relationship with user served by the Identity Provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take one step back and forget about authentication. Without it you would store the user information in your model. The business model, since this information is business information. This is the kind of information you need when you would show a report that contains user information. It doesn't contain any information about authentication or authorization.

Now add security using Ids4. Let's assume that Ids4 has its own database, which is in fact how it should be. Create a user in Ids4 and configure the flow and user to grant access. The result is a user that can login. So then you'll have two seperate users: a login user and a business user.

Before I continue, keep in mind, not all business users require to login. And not all login users have access to this application.

Final step is to link the two together. You should use the `sub` claim for that. <strike>but I would rather add a claim that contains the UserId for the specific application, e.g. `http://myapp1/userid` = `123`.</strike>
Because you can be certain that this key is unique over all apps and exists as claim as it is part of OpenId Connect: in IdentityServer4 the `openid` scope is required (consent is not needed and can't be revoked by the user).

Now about redundancy. Actually there isn't. The information is stored on two locations, but not inside the same database. Consider this, if you would use an external login (e.g. Google) then you would have the same problem, in which case you would copy the information to your local Identity tables.

With Ids4 it isn't much different. But you don't have to copy the information to another Identity table, instead update your business user. But only with business information. Use the UserInfo endpoint to request user information from Ids4.

Keeping both environments seperated is the easiest way. So, there isn't a database relation. This works for all your applications. And changes in either Ids4 or in your applications doesn't affect eachother. You could even replace Ids4 with another oidc server if you want to.

Having removed complexity from your code, it now it comes to configuring Ids4, which is actually an important reason to use Ids4: the flexibility to configure resources, scopes and flows.

One drawback may be that you'll need to maintain the login user on Ids4, while you'll require a business user which is maintained in your application. If you want to manage the login user from your application too, then extend Ids4 with an API to make this possible.

Comment: So to sum it up your recommendation is to have essentially 2 "user" entities. ID4 ApplicationUser and a GameStoreUser, linked via a sub for exmaple? The approach makes sense, i will look into it.

Comment: Yes, the main reason to have two seperate user entities is because they both have a different purpose. Simply put, one is for login only (without knowing anything about the applications) and the other has only meaning in your application (without knowing anything about authentication). The login user can be used for single sign-on as it is not bound to one application. And this way you can keep authorization close to the resource, while Ids4 takes care of authentication.

Comment: You know what, i like it. Let me play around a little and get back to you

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I strongly agree with your suggested approach I'm in a similar situation with a Business application in .NET Core that has its own user entity and I want to create a IS4 Auth Server App to use for authentication. I don't want the 2 applications to be dependent, because there is still the possibility of being able to use the same IS4 also for other applications. I just want to better understand your proposed solution at coding level, so can you please show some sample code? Also I was thinking of using .NET Core User Identity for both the user entities... is it good?

Comment: @CheshireCat For a start you can look at the [sample code of IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/0_overview.html). You can use this code to configure authentication/authorization. Please note that the access token is used for authorization. None of the apps has access to the User context (which is part of IS4). The apps read the User.Identity 'sub' claim (from the access token as part of oidc) to identify the user in your business context. For more information about configuration I suggest you take a look at some of my more recent answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the Identity Provider/DB behind some interfaces. This interfaces return some kind of a DTO. The Web API consumes the interfaces, and returns this DTO as a JSON to the Angular app. It complicates the things, but you have the needed abstraction, and the API doesn't know about the entities.